# What is the proper way to modify OpenGL vertex buffer?

Tags: opengl

I'm setting up a vertex buffer in OpenGL, like this:

```
int vboVertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Later, if I want to add or remove vertices to "vertexData", what is the proper way to do this? Is it even possible? I'm assuming I can't just modify the array directly without re-sending it to the GPU.

If I modify the vertexData array, then call this again:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

...will that overwrite the old buffer with my new data? Or do I also have to delete the old one? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The size of any OpenGL buffer object is set when you call `glBufferData`.  That is, OpenGL will allocate the amount of memory you specify in the second argument of `glBufferData` (which isn't listed in the OP).  In fact, if you call, for example `glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW );` OpenGL will create a buffer of `bufferSize` bytes of *uninitialized data*.

You can load any amount of data (up to the size of the buffer) using `glBufferSubData`, `glMapBuffer`, or any of the other routines for passing data.  The only way to resize the buffer is to call `glBufferData` with a new size for the same buffer id (the value returned from `glGenBuffers`).

That said, you can always use a subset of the data in the buffer (which would be akin to deleting vertices), and if you render using `glDrawElements`, you can randomly access elements in the buffer.  Adding vertices to a buffer would require allocating a larger buffer, and then you'd need to reload all of the data in the buffer.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBufferData

> glBufferData creates a new data store for the buffer object currently bound to target​. Any pre-existing data store is deleted.

This explains a call to `glBufferData` will "reallocate" the data, the buffer will have a new size. All the old data will be lost. If you want to write to only a part of the buffer, use `glBufferSubData` instead.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBufferSubData

Edit: `glBufferSubData` is only if you want to replace data; to resize the buffer instead, you have to call `glBufferData`.

Also, you don't have to destroy the buffer first and generate a new one. Remember the GLuint is only a 'pointer' of sorts for OpenGL. It is not the actual storage, thus it is perfectly fine to reuse the same 'pointer' (if you did not delete it yet of course).

Comment: Instead of saying GLuint is a pointer, it's better to say GLuint is a handle.

Answer (score 4):

1 by using glMapBuffer

```cpp
void mapBuffer(uint &id, void *data, uint size, uint type) {
    glBindBuffer(type, id);
    // get pointer
    void *ptr = glMapBuffer(type, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    // now copy data into memory
    memcpy(ptr, data, size);
    // make sure to tell OpenGL we're done with the pointer
    glUnmapBuffer(type);
}
```

2 by using glBufferSubData

```cpp
 void updateBuffer(uint &id, uint offset, void *data, uint size, uint type) {
        glBindBuffer(type, id);
        glBufferSubData(type, offset, size, data);
    }
```

Specifies the size in bytes of the data store region being replaced

```cpp
mapBuffer(vbo, vertex.data(), sizeof(uint)*vertex.size(), GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
resetBuffer(vbo, vertex.data(), sizeof(uint)*vertex.size(), GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
updateBuffer(vbo, 0, vertex.data(), sizeof(uint)*vertex.size(), GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

if u want u can also used 
`glBufferData` -> but it's delete all the old data and reused the same buffer
`glInvalidateBufferSubData` -> it's put NULL at all the place and now u can feed ur own data.